# thunar: is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle tree view and shortcut-pane?

Tags: shortcut-keys, thunar

Was fooling around and got thunar to stick to the tree view, but I would like to restore it to the shortcut-pane. Is there a keyboard-shortcut to do this?

Comment: ^B for shortcuts, ^E for tree view  (view->side-pane shows this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to enable shortcut pane.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to enable tree view.

Source: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12424